# eMMC interfacing with EC200U SDIO Power domain

Tags: microcontroller, memory, microprocessor, interface, emmc

I need to interface my eMMC([THGBMJG6C1LBAU7](https://www.kioxia.com/content/dam/kioxia/shared/business/memory/mlc-nand/asset/productbrief/KIOXIA_e-MMC_Product_Brief.pdf)) memory with [EC200U](https://www.quectel.com/product/lte-ec200u-series) from Quectel.

The Quectel E200U has two SDIO ports one is working at **3.3V power domain** and

other one is working at **1.8V power domain**.

The eMMC VCC is **3.3V** and VCCQ is **1.8V**.

I am new to eMMC. This is my first design with eMMC.

I have two questions here.

1. To which SDIO in EC200U do I need to connect the eMMC,1.8V SDIO or
   3.3V SDIO.
2. What is the difference between VCC and VCCq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Integrated Circuits have two power inputs, one for the device itself and one for the communication to the outside.

In your case VCC is the power for the eMMC and VCCQ is the power for the communication.
As your datasheet shows

VCC on the eMMC should be between 2.7 and 3.6 Volt,

VCCQ can be between 1.70 and 1.95 Volt **OR** between 2.7 and 3.6 Volt.

If you choose to use 1.8 Volt for VCCQ, connect it to the 1.8 Power Domain, if you choose to use 3.3 Volt for VCCQ, connect it to the 3.3 Power Domain.

Your decision should be considering power consumption of the communication, noise on the power lines and other electromagnetic interferences in youre device.